# VNC connect to background user

Tags: users, remote-desktop, vnc, remote, remote-access

Is it somehow possible to allow local VNC connection to background user to other people while I'm myself working as the main user?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could install a VNC server like vnc4server, tightvnc or tigervnc from the repository, then start separate sessions for separate users via the `vncserver` command.